# Delete unused functions from Django models. Migrations error

Tags: django, migration

Do anyone know how to delete functions from old migrations file? My Imagefield in Django models have upload_to argument linked for "generate_name" function. Now i changed function to "generate_path". But when I'm trying to do anything with "./manage.py" it makes AttributeError

```
'module' object has no attribute 'generate_name'
```

But I don't need this function any more.

Comment: did you try to makemigrations and migrate?

Comment: I thought there is some native way to do this. So typical situation.

Comment: makemigrations don't work, same error. Although previous answer help manually correct migrations file.

Comment: try making an alias `generate_name` method that just calls your new `generate_path` then make a migration... can you then delete the alias after that?

Comment: @SergiiV. did the solution with renaming work? also have you use anywhere else the function name 'generate_name' - in your project?

Comment: @BogdiG I replaced generate_name in view. But renaming in migrations files work.

Comment: @Anentropic I'm already decided this problem with help of hand renaming in migrations. But I think it won't help. It looks like without renaming, you must keep everything that you used, and it was placed in migrations

Comment: is this with the newer Django migrations or with South migrations?

Comment: newer Django migrations

Comment: Just [squash migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/migrations/#squashing-migrations), that's it