# Why can't I delete a custom function in django models migration?

Tags: python, django

I created a custom function to use in another class

models.py

```
class DateRangeFunc(models.Func):
    function = "daterange"
    output_field = DateRangeField()

class Foo(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    start_datetime = models.DateField()
    end_datetime = models.DateField()

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            ExclusionConstraint(
                name="exclude_overlapping",
                expressions=(
                    (
                        DateRangeFunc(
                            "start_datetime", "end_datetime", RangeBoundary()
                        ),
                        RangeOperators.OVERLAPS,
                    ),

                ),
            ),
        ]
```

`DateRangeFunc` is the custom method I created to help write an exclusion constraint.

I want to delete the Foo model as well as the DateRangeFunc class because both are not used anymore.

When I try to `makemigrations` after removing both from models.py I get the following error:

```
File "foo/migrations/0012_auto_20220907_1238.py", line 31, in Migration
    constraint=django.contrib.postgres.constraints.ExclusionConstraint(expressions=((foo.models.DateRangeFunc('start_datetime', 'end_datetime', django.contrib.postgres.fields.ranges.RangeBoundary()), '&&')), name='exclude_overlapping'),
AttributeError: module 'foo.models' has no attribute 'DateRangeFunc'
```

because it is still present in the old migration file `0012_auto_20220907_1238.py`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/migrations/#considerations-when-removing-model-fields

I should be able to add a `system_check_removed_details` if necessary (it is not in my case) and then squash -> remove models -> remove migration file. i.e.

"Keep this stub field for as long as any migrations which reference the field exist. **For example, after squashing migrations and removing the old ones, you should be able to remove the field completely."**

However, I can't run a squash because the same error occurs. That class doesn't seem to be able to be deleted the same way other classes (models). A similar SO post: [Delete unused functions from Django models. Migrations error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31361177/delete-unused-functions-from-django-models-migrations-error)

explains what I want to be able to do, but there doesn't seem to be a working answer (I have tried the suggestions in the comments)

My question is why can't I delete a function like I can delete a model and if I can, how?

Answer (score 0):

try to delete all related migrations and then run commands makemigrations and migrate.

Comment: Yes, deleting migrations works but it seems odd that I'd have to do that in order to delete a method. The docs say manually editing (which includes deleting) should only be done in rare cases. Is this a truly rare case?

Comment: I don't say this is a truly rare case. but something Django shows this type of error.